# Can the feature "Persistent Rage" make a Rage last for more than 1 minute?

Tags: dnd-5e, barbarian, rage, duration

The feature "Persistent Rage" states that your rage ends **early** only if you end it yourself or fall unconscious.

The normal duration of a Rage is 1 minute.

Can a Rage lasts for more than 1 minute if the rager has this feature ?

I personally believe that the answer is no, but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### No, it still ends after one minute

The rules on Rage define the concept of a rage ending *early* (Player's Handbook page 48):

> Your rage lasts for 1 minute. It ends early if you are knocked unconscious or if your turn ends and you haven't attacked a hostile creature since your last turn or taken damage since then.

Persistent Rage only affects rages ending early (Player's Handbook page 49):

> Beginning at 15th level, your rage is so fierce that it ends early only if you fall unconscious or if you choose to end it.

The rage still lasts one minute, but cannot end abruptly as easily.

Comment: As said before, this was a phenomenal catch that's easy to miss. Have an updoot.

Comment: The bit about not attacking things is the important part of this ability. Nothing is quite as awkward as losing rage while trying to close on archers far enough back that you need more than 1 turn to get to them. Enjoy your +1.

Comment: @Bagahnoodles Why every barbarian should carry a whole pile of long-ranged thrown weapons.  ;)

Comment: @Yakk could I multiclass a monk and catch the arrows that they fire at me?

Comment: @JohnDvorak of course, if your DM allows multiclassing. I do feel obliged to say that barbarian/monk multiclassing likely won't make a lot of sense, roleplay-wise. Also, monks use dex as their primary ability, while barbarians use strength. I would rather recommend multiclassing as a fighter to get action surge, second wind and, if you take champion fighter, critical on 19-20 (which synergizes very well with a barbarians reckless attack and brutal critical, raising your crit chance to 19% and dealing tons of damage on a critical hit: e.g. 1d12*2+3d12. Not to mention the potential 4-5 attacks)

Answer (score 0):

## Player's intent is the duration

You are using the word "early" to justify the inclusion of 1 minute. You are wrong. As persistent rage also has a neat word added to it; the word "only".

Now, since Persistent Rage's description **does not** include a duration, no duration should be applied. Rules as written the *only* two things that end a rage are the unconscious state *or* you choosing to end it. The word early, although may imply a set duration, doesn't list the set duration.

Example, if I wanted to rage for a week straight, long resting and everything (which is allowable since long resting can be sleeping *or* light activity) then boom I get knocked unconscious, my rage would end *earlier* than my intent.

My point is, since no duration is set for Persistent Rage. Then the players intent is the duration.

Comment: I suppose that can be a valid interpretation.

Comment: Hi Mpti! Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. In future if you can double check your posts for spelling, grammar and correct capitalization that would be appreciated. Not doing so is likely to attract downvotes. Thanks for participating and happy gaming.

Comment: I think that sleep makes you unconscious (in a mechanical sense) so if you do that thing for a week you will be subjected to exhaustion (perhaps), and or your rage will end when you become unconscious at the point that you sleep. I suggest you re check that part about sleep before making that part of your example.  If your example confined itself to a whole adventure day it would stand up a bit better.